# The ViewPager doesn't work to swipe the fragments

Tags: android, android-viewpager

The ViewPager doesn't work to swipe the fragment. I'm using Drawer activity then added a `BottomNavigationView`, and in the main content i added a `FrameLayout` to be a fragment container and positioned below the `TabLayout` and above the `BottomNaigationView`. Then I made a class named `PagerAdapter extends FragmnetPagerAdapter`.

I made a constructor and implement the `getItem()` and `getCount()` methods, then in the `MainActivity` I initialized all the views by its id but when I run the app all works except the the swipe among the fragment with the `Viewpager`. What should I do more to make it work.

This is my `PagerAdapter` class:

```
public class PageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private int numberOfTabs;

    public PageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int numberOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.numberOfTabs = numberOfTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case(0) : return new HomeFragment();
            case(1) : return new CouponFragment();
            default : return null;
            }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return numberOfTabs;
    }
}
```

Here is my xml file:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
```

Tool Bar with TextView to set the title

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/my_title"
                android:text="Title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Here the TabLayout is added with three tabs Home,Coupons and Notifications. I want the ViewPager to swipe among the three tabs

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/color"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/color"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/fadeWhite">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tab_home"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Home"
            style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
            />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tab_coupons"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Coupons"
            style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
            />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tab_notifiactions"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Notifiactions"
            style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/navBar"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />
```

Here is the `MainActivity`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);

    tab_home = (TabItem) findViewById(R.id.tab_home);
    tab_coupons = (TabItem) findViewById(R.id.tab_coupons);
    tab_noti = (TabItem) findViewById(R.id.tab_notifiactions);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

    adapter = new PageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),tabLayout.getTabGravity());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    //setupToolBar
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    my_title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_title);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    my_title.setText(toolbar.getTitle());
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Comment: You should post your MainActivity or Fragment code in which you assign the adapter to the view pager

Comment: @NicolaGallazzi i added the MainActivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
adapter = new PageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),tabLayout.getTabGravity());
```

You should pass to your adapter the tabs count. tabLayout.getTabGravity() https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html#getTabGravity() returns the current gravity used for laying out tabs.